# AutoHotkey go to certain folder from active folder by ignoring full path

Tags: directory, autohotkey, shortcut, subdirectory

I have an opened folder:

> "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Named_Folder"

==================================

Under "Named_Folder"
there is folder called "1"
and under that folder there is another one called "2".

I want to create a one letter shortcut to go from active "Named_Folder" to folder "2" so the path would look like this:

> "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Named_Folder\1\2"

Here i need to mention that folder "1" and "2" have always the same name, but "Named_Folder" has always a different name.

So maybe I could improve this topic title: Go 2 directories down from active directory with one letter shortcut ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") ; explorer

F1::
for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
try Fullpath := window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
; IfExist, %Fullpath%\1\
    Run, %Fullpath%\1
return

F2::
for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
try Fullpath := % window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
; IfExist, %Fullpath%\1\2\
    Run, %Fullpath%\1\2
return

#If
```

EDIT:
navigating to a directory without opening a new window:

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") ; explorer

F1::
for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
try Fullpath := % window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
IfExist, %Fullpath%\1\
    NavRun( Fullpath "\1")
return

F2::
for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
try Fullpath := window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
IfExist, %Fullpath%\1\2\
     NavRun( Fullpath "\1\2")
return

#If


; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774094
GetActiveExplorer() {
    static objShell := ComObjCreate("Shell.Application")
    WinHWND := WinActive("A")    ; Active window
    for Item in objShell.Windows
        if (Item.HWND = WinHWND)
            return Item        ; Return active window object
    return -1    ; No explorer windows match active window
}

NavRun(Path) {
    if (-1 != objIE := GetActiveExplorer())
        objIE.Navigate(Path)
    else
        Run, % Path
}
```

https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/102127-navigating-explorer-directories/#entry634365

Comment: thnx a lot! Works like a charm ! Is it possible to open the same folder "2" in the same window ? 'cause now it opens the desired folder in a new window.

Comment: I`ve found a solution on https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/102127-navigating-explorer-directories/#entry634365.